# Undefined variables on page.eval function using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, bots, eval, puppeteer, headless

When I run this in my code it says that dottt is undefined, but why does it take in the pdfcitystatezipselector correctly. If I replace dottt with a string literal it works perfect.

```
const pdfcitystatezipselector = 'body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(6) > span';
  const dottt = "111111";

  await page.$eval(pdfdotselector, (element1, dotttt) => {


    element1.innerHTML = dottt;
  });
```

Comment: I'm assuming that `dotttt` should be `dottt` - otherwise I can't make any sense of it at all. Note that there are two separate variables called `dottt`. The first one is declared `const dottt = "111111";`. But in the scope of the function there is another one (the argument to the function), which overrides the first one. It's undefined probably because that function is only called with one argument.

Comment: I am just trying to use a variable that has been declared outside the function inside the function. It keeps giving me an undefined value when I do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the `dotttt` argument to the `$eval` function:

```js
const pdfcitystatezipselector = 'body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(6) > span';
const dottt = "111111";

await page.$eval(pdfdotselector, 
    (element1, dotttt) => {
       element1.innerHTML = dottt;
    },
    dotttt); // here
```

Comment: I tried your exact code and it still says " ReferenceError: dottt is not defined" The code I used is below.

Comment: `const pdfdotselector = 'body > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > span';
      const dottt = "111111";

      await page.$eval(pdfdotselector,
        (element1, dotttt) => {
          element1.innerHTML = dottt;
      },
      dottt);`